# java библиотека для работы с CAN

Tags: java, поиск-библиотек, library, can

Есть плата с CAN bus - ([Controller Area Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus)) и программа на Java на ней, нужно добавить поддержку обмена по CAN. В сети ничего внятного не нашел, кроме переделывания С-шных библиотек. В идеале что-нибудь кроссплатформенное, ну или под Linux.

Comment: берите jni, заворачивайте библиотеку и готово

Comment: а что такое CAN - можно инфо для полных профанов?

Comment: @Barmaley CAN (англ. Controller Area Network — сеть контроллеров) — стандарт промышленной сети, ориентированный, прежде всего, на объединение в единую сеть различных исполнительных устройств и датчиков. Режим передачи — последовательный, широковещательный, пакетный.
По первой ссылке в той  же википедии все написано.

Comment: CAN это такая банда немецкая есть :)